# CSS DIV hover not working in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

When I hover a DIV element in Internet Explorer 8, my CSS rules are not applying correctly.

The below code works with no problems:

```
<div id="album-view">
<div class="loading"></div>
<div id="main">
 here is my all code, this code works.
</div>
</div>
```

However, in this next excerpt, the code is not working with the `.loading` and the `display:none;` attribute:

```
<div id="album-view">
  <div class="loading" style="display:none;"></div>
  <div id="main">
   Not working
  </div>
</div>
```

If anyone has any suggestions, please help guide me in the correct direction.

You can see my test server, `nasir.herobo.com/s.html#!/4` or screenshots https://i.stack.imgur.com/Crvmy.png [image]

Comment: can you post some more complete code, like your CSS or if you included the hover pseudo directly in your HTML?

Comment: It's a lot of code, You can see my test server, nasir.herobo.com/s.html#!/4

Comment: Give the div a background color and see if hovers work. IE seems to let things pass through transparent bits. Which can be remedied by a transparent image.

Answer (score 0):

In IE8 your display: none;, since its an inline style, isn't being overridden by your css. You would have to use JavaScript to change the inline style, or add the display: none; to your css instead of the element. IE8 and less has different hierarchy with styles than newer browsers.

Answer (score -1):

I recently had a css :hover problem with ie8.  My opacity change was not working correctly on hover because the div with the :hover style applied contained child div with a css position attribute of 'relative'.  For my purposes, 'relative' was not a necessary style.  Changing the position attribute to static did the trick, and the opacity change on hover worked as intended.

It took me several hours long sessions researching for the answer, and ended up solving myself.  Hope the tid-bit helps someone else.